# Adding to cart Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a ecom website by Django and add products to cart, but when I run it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

The codes goes here:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='product', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    detail = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    digital =  models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ecoshop:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("ecoshop:add-to-cart", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("ecoshop:remove-from-cart", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

views.py

```
def addtocart(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product, customer=request.user, order = False)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(customer=request.user, complete = False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(product__pk = product.pk).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "Added quantity Item")
            return redirect("shop:cart", pk=pk)
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "Item added to your cart")
            return redirect("shop:cart", pk=pk)
    else:
        date_order = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(customer=request.user, date_order=date_order)
        order.items.add(order_item) 
        messages.info(request, "Item added to your cart")
        return redirect("shop:cart", pk=pk)
    
    
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
        cartItem = order.get_cart_items
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_items': 0, 'get_cart_total': 0}
        cartItem = order['get_cart_items']
    categories = Category.objects.filter(is_sub=False)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_items': 0, 'get_cart_total': 0}
    cart = Order.objects.filter(customer=request.user)
    context = { 'items': items, 'order': order, 'categories': categories, 'cartItem': cartItem, 'cart': cart}
    return render(request, 'pages/cart.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.price}}$</p>
                <a href="{{object.get_add_to_cart_url}}" class="btn btn-info update-cart" data-action='add' data-product="{{product.id}}" type="button" style="border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    + <i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I'm trying to create a ecom website by Django and add products to cart, but when I run it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what error are you running into?

Comment: What exactly does not work, what should happen, what is happening instead?